# How do you open document/folder/program using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a command or a script that I can use to open "whatever" on my computer using Autohotkey?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its called RUN

> http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/TutorialLaunch.htm